# What is being set as np.unit8(array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, enumeration, opencv

I am trying to understand how this function works, I have previously identified arrays (at least my understanding is that they are arrays) and then I'm seeing this block of code appear that I'm not sure what it does or how it does it. Any help with an explanation would be amazing. I'm trying to decipher a freelancers code that doesn't work in order to fix it and/or make it better.

This is for a project that I'm unable to give much detail on. all I can say is that I'm working with histograms.

This is the code in question:

```
x = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
array = np.copy(x)
# theres a chunk cut due to NDA
for oldval, newval in enumerate(x):                 
    thing = np.where(array[:, :, 0] == oldval)
    array[thing[0], thing[1], 0] = np.uint8(newval)
final = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
```

There are no errors or results to share.

Comment: as it stands your line of code makes no sense & as far as I am aware is not valid in Python

Comment: This is a single line of code generated from a for loop. the loop is updated in the question

Comment: what is `array`? is it the same shape as `oyuv`?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it, error on my side. "array" is just a placeholder for the actual array. the oyuv was the array I was talking about but I meant to replace oyuv with the word "array" haha, just me making a mistake when posting.

Comment: it's fixed, I'm still lost on what it's doing. I cant seem to find it anywhere online.

Comment: as `array` is an image what does it look like after the replacement operation?

Comment: I'm suspect there are bits in the NDA section that would make change my best guess, which is that this code changes an image into a perceptual color space so that pixels with a certain chrominance chararacteristic can be isolated and changed. It's odd, though, since in YUV, it's the UV that encodes chrominance, not V. So either something very clever is going on, or you inherited code written by someone who only partially understood what they were doing.